# Adding items to external enum [java]

Tags: java, enums

I'm working with a library that has an enum class, though for what I want, I need to add a new value to the enum.
Would there be a way to call the class and add it, or would I have to copy the file from the library to add my value?
I know I can't extend or implement an enum into a new class. So I'm trying to find the best and most efficient way of getting what I want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need to add a new value to the enum

Its impossible. But you can edit source code of library. Or change your design keep enum as is.